# Prove that $\lfloor N/ \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor^2\rfloor = 1$ for $N > 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that $\lfloor N/ \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor^2\rfloor = 1$ for $N > 8$.

This is simple to check by listing and the only exceptions are for $N = 2,3,8$.  I am looking for a simple proof if possible.  This problem arises from solving polynomials with constraints on the range of coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $N = n^2 + k$ such that $0 \leq k < 2n+1$ so that we have $n^2 \leq N < (n+1)^2$. Then $\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor = n$.

Now, we can simplify as below:

$$
\Bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{{\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor}^2} \Bigg\rfloor
= \bigg\lfloor \frac{n^2 + k}{n^2} \bigg\rfloor
= 1 + \bigg\lfloor \frac{k}{n^2} \bigg\rfloor
$$

Since $k < 2n + 1$, we also have

$$ \frac{k}{n^2} < \frac{2n + 1}{n^2} = \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} $$

Thus, $1 + \Big\lfloor \frac{k}{n^2} \Big\rfloor = 1 + \Big\lfloor \frac{2}{n} \Big\rfloor$ and for this to be $1$, we need $\Big\lfloor \frac{2}{n} \Big\rfloor = 0$ i.e. $n \geq 3$ or equivalently $N \geq 9$.

Comment: Very good and this helped answer several other related problems.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor$ then we'll have $a^2\le N< (a+1)^2 = a^2+2a+1$

So we have $N/\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor^2 \le (a^2+2a)/a^2 = 1+2/a$. So if $a>2$ (ie $a\ge 3$ or $N\ge 9$) we'll have that $N/\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor^2 < 2$. And of course it will be no less than $1$ so the integral part must be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions),
$$
\sqrt{N}-1\lt\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor\le\sqrt{N}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
1\le\frac{N}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor^2}&\lt\frac{N}{\left(\sqrt{N}-1\right)^2}\\
&=2-\frac{\left(\sqrt{N}-2\right)^2-2}{\left(\sqrt{N}-1\right)^2}\\[6pt]
&\lt2\tag2
\end{align}
$$
when $N\gt\left(2+\sqrt2\right)^2=6+4\sqrt2\doteq11.656854$, so we just need to verify $(2)$ for $N\in\{9,10,11\}$ by hand. Because $\frac99,\frac{10}9,\frac{11}9\lt2$, we have shown that for $N\gt8$,
$$
1\le\frac{N}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor^2}\lt2\tag3
$$

Answer (score 1):

From

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor\le\sqrt N<\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor+1,$$
we have
$$1\le\frac N{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor^2}<\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor+1}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor}\right)^2<2$$

as of $\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor\ge3$.